# Xcode keeps showing the beachball when I select something

Tags: macos, performance, xcode, osx-yosemite

When I select something in the xcode editor and then try to select some other text, the spinning beachball comes up and i have to wait for a couple of seconds before i can continue working. I have the new mac pro, and thought I wouldn't have to deal with problems like this. I am running the beta for Yosemite, so that might be the issue, but I want to confirm my suspicions before I go back to Mavericks. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you have any xcode plugin installed?

Comment: not that i'm aware of

Comment: I am in similar situation.  Did you figure out what was the cause?